# React Nativ iOS APP is loading black screen instead of main React Native Splash which I designed

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am running react-native APP and try to run ios Part. It's Launch successful but with black screen. Also I can not see any option on Launcher. Please see below image.

[image]

See simulator

[image]

Again, It's React Native and me want to run on ios simulator

Comment: Share to us ur code

Comment: It's react-native, can you tell me which area of code should I send?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to let you know, I solved the problem by myself. I was doing something wrong on info.plist. That was code which was getting issue.

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I just removed that and problem resolved

Comment: You can also uncheck "Supports multiple windows" in the xcodeproj "General" tab of the project, in the "Deployment Info" section.